# Item in list being removed without reference

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this loop that does not mention a list, yet after it is done the list is missing one of its items.

```
print(numlist)
testlist=numlist
print(testlist)

for i in range(5):
    print(numlist)
    list1=[]
    for numbers in testlist:
        list1.append(numbers[i])

    print(str(numlist)+'before')

    for numbers in testlist: #NUMLIST IS LOSING SOMETHING HERE
        if max(list1)>numbers[i]: 
            testlist.remove(numbers)

    print(str(numlist)+'after')
```

which outputs

```
[[13, 13, 13, 2, 2], [13, 13, 13, 3, 3]]before
[[13, 13, 13, 3, 3]]after
```

Comment: Where do `numlist` and `testlist` come from? Are you sure they're not the same list?

Comment: In addition to the other answers you can copy your list by `testlist = numlist[:]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a reference to the `numlist` when you do

```
testlist=numlist
```

Hence whatever changes you do to the `numlist` will be reflected in `testlist`. Similarly, any changes done to the `testlist` will be reflected also in `numlist`. One way to create a copy of the list is to use

```
testlist = numlist.copy()
```

This way you clone a list without creating any reference object to the original list.

As [Håken Lid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1977847/h%C3%A5ken-lid) 
 and [benvc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9958942/benvc) mentioned in the comments, you could also do

```
testlist = numlist[:]
```

Comment: Another common way to create a shallow copy of a list is using slice notation: `testlist = numlist[:]`

Comment: @HåkenLid: True that. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that somewhere before the code you posted you have `numlist = testlist`.
If that's the case, you should use `numlist = list(testlist)`, to create another instance of the same list.

Here is what is happening:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = a
print a # OUTPUT: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b.pop()
print a # OUTPUT: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

This happens because when you set `numlist = testlist`, both the variable names reference to the same list.
If you cast it as a new list, you'll duplicate your list in memory, so each variable point to a different list.

this is not a new argument on SO, this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) provides some really interesting answers and explanations on why this happens, which are the solutions, and pro/cons of each solution

Comment: @buran that's a clear explanation. scroll down to the [assignment](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html#h_assignment) section to a specific insight.

Comment: I am not able to change the comment/link, but I added it as it's really good explanation on python names

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have created a shallow copy of numlist. Both testlist and numlist will have the same address with shallow copy(bitwise copy). When any action is performed on any one of the lists it is reflected to both lists because of the same address. 
Create a new instance for testlist so that testlist and numlist have different addresses but same data.
You can use something like this:

```
testlist = numlist.copy()
```